# Change help link in the Visual Editor of MediaWiki

Tags: localization, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Is there a way to change the help link in the toolbar dropdown in the new visual editor of MediaWiki?

I tried setting

```
"visualeditor-help-link":"mw:Help:VisualEditor/User guide/de"
```

in

```
"extentsions/VisualEditor/modules/ve-wmf/i18n/de.json"
```

as proposed [here](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-VisualEditor/blob/master/modules/ve-wmf/i18n/qqq.json), but then my MediaWiki could not parse the JSON file. My goal is to link to the MediaWiki help page, that can be found [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:VisualEditor/User_guide/de). The normal version:

```
"visualeditor-help-link":"[https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:VisualEditor/User_guide/de]"
```

did not work, neither did this:

```
"[[{{MediaWiki:visualeditor-helppagelink}}|Hilfe]]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never ever change the source code of MediaWiki core or any extension. It makes an upgrade process much more hard and complicated. There are other ways to achieve a high customization of the user interface language :)

For your problem, it should be enough to create the following page in your wiki (like any other page, but you need the editinterface user right, which is assigned to sysops by default):

```
MediaWiki:visualeditor-help-link
```

Put the link you want to use into the textarea (without any wikitext, e.g. "Help:VisualEditor" (without any ")) and save the page.

After reloading the VisualEditor (maybe you need to clear your browser's cache using Ctrl + F5) the link should point to the new target you specified in the message above. If you use a message cache, it is maybe needed to rebuilt it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this points me into the right direction. However just using 'https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:VisualEditor/User_guide/de' mediawiki will prepend my wiki's url.

Comment: You need to use internal wiki links, for your example use "mw:Help:VisualEditor/User_guide/de".

Comment: Thanks however it tell me that the title of the requested page is invalid, empty or an invalid language link of another wiki... I guess I have to turn the interwiki links on somehow?

Comment: You need working interwiki links (`local` needs to be true, so that links will be forwarded to the target wiki). In interwiki links I can't really assist, sorry :/